# Who is Rav Tzvi HaLevi?

Tags: names, genealogy

Below is a ketuba for a bride name Chaya bat Yehuda, and Yehuda's father is shown as **Rav Tzvi HaLevy**.

I know for a fact from people who knew him and from multiple original source documents including other ketubas and birth certificates that Yehuda's father (my great-grandfather) was named Mordechai, known as Mochi Iancu in Romania. They adopted the surname Schwartz. I also know that Mordechai was no Levi, since his son was my grandfather and we went to shul together 100s of times. Nor was anyone (relevant) adopted.

Since Zvi HaLevy was not the name of her grandfather, I'm wondering if perhaps it  might be a symbolic or mystical name, or perhaps some other explanation.

[image: image of ketuba showing relevant names discussed above]

Comment: I have never seen a Jewish legal document in which leviyim are referenced with the words המכונה הלוי. This wording means "who is known as HaLevy" and perhaps means that it was a nickname for a non-Levy.

Comment: I have known Schwartzes who were Leviim. Maybe the "who is known as" is pointing to the adopted surname of Schwartz.

Comment: well, the scope of the question is at the bottom: " I'm wondering if perhaps it might be a symbolic or mystical name, or perhaps some other explanation."  by symbolic name, I thought that maybe Rav Tzvi HaLevi might be like writing "ben Yisroel" for a convert. it not a real person, but rather a custom, perhaps when the father is not known or not present.